# How to use vue components in a svelte app?

Tags: vue.js, svelte

I really love using Svelte but at this moment, one of its cons is the lack of ready-to-use components for Svelte.  I want to use vue-atlaskit in a project, but I really prefer using Svelte.  Is it possible to use vue components inside a Svelte app?

I guess it all should be just "web-components", but I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I checked with people in the Svelte Discourse. There is no simple way to do that. The suggestion is to convert the UI components I need from Vue to Svelte.

Comment: That seems to contradict [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-web-components-svelte/). I have not tried yet but am about to.

Comment: @AlenSiljak any update on that?

Comment: @StevenLinn, not directly. I've tried Astro, which allows using multiple frameworks on the same page. And, for Web Components, I prefer Lit. Haven't used any of those in a production application yet, though.

Comment: Unfortunatley there isn't an explanation, but [this comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4971#issuecomment-814373600) from a Svelte github member suggests that Vue just drops into Svelte "To use Vue in a Svelte app, use Vue as you normally would."

Curious what changed after the few months between the Github comment and your findings.

Answer (score 1):

While not a comprehensive answer, I would add some findings on the topic:

As you suggested, I would try with Web Components. According to [Custom Elements Everywhere](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/) the support for Web Components is fairly high for both frameworks. Vue [states](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html) that the support is 100% although the site shows less so there is some discrepancy. But basic tests pass 100%. Svelte is also at 100%. This paints a fairly positive picture.

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71304201/how-to-use-web-components-in-svelte) on SO that refers to consuming Web Components in Svelte.

Here is another reference [article](https://dzone.com/articles/create-amp-publish-web-components-with-vue-cli-3) on how to create web components with Vue 3.

Note: I will try to update the answer as I learn more. I will be testing this out on a migration of a PWA from Vue to Svelte, where I plan first to use Svelte components in an existing Vue app and then perhaps switch to using Vue components in a Svelte app, depending on how things go with rewriting.